# How to save bulk document in Cloudant using Java or Spark - Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cloudant

Cloudant Client library available in Java that will store one document at a time,

```
CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account("accounbt")
                    .username("username").password("password")
                    .disableSSLAuthentication().build();*/

            Database db = client.database("databaseName", true);

            db.save(jsonObject);
```

Is there any way to save bulk document  in cloudant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that can enable to upload bulk upload,

```
CloudantClient client = ClientBuilder.account("accounbt")
                        .username("username").password("password")
                        .disableSSLAuthentication().build();*/

Database db = client.database("databaseName", true);

List<JSONObject> arrayJson = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayJson.add(new JSONObject("{data:hello}"));
arrayJson.add(new JSONObject("{data:hello1}"));
arrayJson.add(new JSONObject("{data:hello2}"));
db.bulk(arrayJson);
```

Comment: You should **not** turn off SSL Authentication for connections to Cloudant, you are opening yourself up to security problems.

Comment: why is it causing any issue?

Comment: Disabling SSL Authentication means that host name verification and certificate chain validation is **not** performed. Meaning someone could potentially pretend to be cloudant take your credentials and access your private data.