# What is the best approach to update a document in cloudant if available or else insert the document using Java cloudant API

Tags: java, cloudant

With reference to [blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838703/how-to-save-bulk-document-in-cloudant-using-java-or-spark-java) I am able to upload documents in bulk. My problem is few of the documents are already existing in cloudant. So the suggested approach is failing. Please suggest how to handdle bulk add if the documents are not existing in cloudant else bluk update if the docuemnts are existing.

Comment: Check if an `upsert` opertation exists which creates a new document in case it is absence or updates it otherwise. Otherwise, you'll have to query first to see which documents already exist and fire 2 operations instead; update and create.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.. But the "cloudant-client-2.6.2.jar" dont have any "upsert" operation. 

so, now the only option is to 
1. pull each document and check if it exist.
2. If not found then add it.
3. If found then Update it.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me:

```
 public void upsert(List<JsonObject> bulkData,String dbName)
{
    if (bulkData == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(bulkData.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    if(null==dbName || dbName.length() <1){
        return;
    }

    int totalDocumentsToSave = 0;
    int totalDocumentToInsert = 0;
    int totalDocumentToUpdate = 0;
    int totalUpdatesFailed=0;
    int totalInsertsFailed =0;

    totalDocumentsToSave = bulkData.size();


    Database db = client.database(dbName, false);

        try {
            for (JsonObject aDoc : bulkData) {
                 if (aDoc.get("_id") != null) {
                     String _id= aDoc.get("_id").getAsString();

                     if(db.contains(_id))
                     {
                         try
                         {
                             Map<String, String>    aDocOnCloudant = db.getAllDocsRequestBuilder()
                                       .keys(_id)
                                       .includeDocs(true)
                                       .build()
                                       .getResponse()
                                       .getIdsAndRevs();

                                String _revId = aDocOnCloudant.get(_id);
                                aDoc.addProperty("_rev", _revId);
                                db.update(aDoc);
                                totalDocumentToUpdate++;
                         }
                         catch(Exception e)
                         {
                            totalUpdatesFailed++; 
                         }

                     }
                     else
                     {
                         try
                         {
                         db.save(aDoc);
                         totalDocumentsToSave++;
                         }
                         catch(Exception e)
                         {
                             totalInsertsFailed++;
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }

            db.ensureFullCommit();

}
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        String log = " .Number of Documents to Save: " + totalDocumentsToSave +
                     " .Number of Documents inserted: " + totalDocumentToInsert +
                     " .Number of Documents to Updated: " + totalDocumentToUpdate +
                     " .Failed Inserts: " + totalInsertsFailed +
                     " .Failed Updates: " + totalUpdatesFailed +
                     " .Cloudant full commit completed";
        System.out.println(log);

}
```